# Question about relativity inspired by Dragon's Egg -- would creatures living in high-g experience relativistic effects?

Tags: gravity, speed-of-light, physical-chemistry

I am thinking that on a world where falling objects (perhaps meteorites) achieve a high fraction of C when they land, and their nervous systems are much faster, they would understand relativity much sooner in their history. For example, they could perform Michaelson-Morley experiments where they would not need the ultra precise equipment that M-M had.

On the other hand, because of relativity, maybe they would not notice any effects that humans on Earth don't. I am pretty sure the former is true -- they would have understood first the speed of light as being finite much sooner than we did and relativity might show itself in everyday life.

(I do not recall what the book said on this -- it was written by a physicist. I also  realize this might not be the right place for this question, but it is not a question about a book -- it is a question about the experiences of a creature who, because of their physiologies and the high gravity planet they live might be exposed close up to objects moving closer to C than we do and might be able to experience such velocity because of their very fast nervous systems.)

Comment: A current question on *Dragon's Egg*: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/268128/116908

Comment: yeah but i asked that in a fiction forum. i am wondering if there really is an physics answer -- i am not hopeful of getting a correct answer in scifi.

Comment: Sure, Scifi.SE isn't the place to get definitive real-world physics answers, but the answers (& some comments) on that page do have info that may be useful, especially for people who haven't read the story. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg